# Joomla while installing javascript error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of null

Tags: javascript, joomla, joomla3.2

I get this error while installing Joomla. It's a Javascript error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of null
```

Joomla 3.2 stable version

Why does this error occur?

Comment: If I rightly remember, Mootools dependencies were removed from the Joomla installation and were converted to Javascript and jQuery. It might be possible that they might have missed something which is causing a conflict, however I haven't seen any posts regarding this issue with Joomla 3.2 stable. Try installing a copy of Joomla on a local host wuch as xampp or wamp to see if you get this error on there. If not then I would have thought it's something to do with your server.

Comment: yes exactly I'am getting it on wamp

Comment: Oh. In that case, ensure you're running the latest version of Wamp with PHP 5.4, else try installing on Xampp instead. If you already have an online host, then install on there.

Comment: my wamp is php 5.4, i'am installing on a subfolder

Comment: I've tried to put joomla 2.5, now I get an error that jQuery is not defined, can't figure it out why thats happening

Comment: There is definitely some sort of conflict. It might be coming from something else you have installed on Wamp. As mentioned before, try using Xampp. I don't receive any of these errors when installing Joomla 2.5 or 3.2

Answer (score 7):

I had changed `max_execution_time` in php.ini from 30 to 90

```
max_execution_time=90
```

Then it works!

Comment: This happens when you have a slow pc

Comment: 4 GB RAM on a 3.6 Ghz intel core i5 processor with 1 GB integraated graphics card and 2 gb dedicated graphics card. I don't think that's slow. Anyways, the answer solved my issue so thanks :)

Comment: I though I were about to leave joomla! But after your answer, I can continue with it.

Answer (score 0):

I realized what the problem is, not enough time
try increase max_execution_time
it helped me